# PyOpenGL "Attempt to retrieve context when no valid context" - seems to be Linux specific?

Tags: opengl, graphics, python, graphics-programming

I've been trying to learn PyOpenGL, so I'm still pretty clueless about what's going on. I've been following a video series. I couldn't get it to stop throwing "Attempt to retrieve context when no valid context", so I tried copying the code directly from the GitHub repo of the video series I was following along with, but it still throws the same error! I've seen a few people encounter the same issue on Linux in my research but with not solutions to the issue. If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Here's the code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram, compileShader


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        glClearColor(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)
        self.shader = self.createShader("shaders/vertex.txt", "shaders/fragment.txt")
        glUseProgram(self.shader)
        self.triangle = Triangle()
        self.mainLoop()

    def createShader(self, vertexFilepath, fragmentFilepath):
        with open(vertexFilepath, "r") as f:
            vertex_src = f.readlines()

        with open(fragmentFilepath, "r") as f:
            fragment_src = f.readlines()

        shader = compileProgram(
            compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
            compileShader(fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER),
        )

        return shader

    def mainLoop(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            # check events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False

            # refresh screen
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

            glUseProgram(self.shader)
            glBindVertexArray(self.triangle.vao)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, self.triangle.vertex_count)
            pygame.display.flip()

            # timing
            self.clock.tick(60)
        self.quit()

    def quit(self):
        self.triangle.destroy()
        glDeleteProgram(self.shader)
        pygame.quit()


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self):
        # x, y z, r, g, b
        self.vertices = (
            -0.5,
            -0.5,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.5,
            -0.5,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.5,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
        )

        self.vertices = np.array(self.vertices, dtype=np.float32)

        self.vertex_count = 3

        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        self.vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBufferData(
            GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertices.nbytes, self.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW
        )

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(0)) // OpenGL.error.Error: Attempt to retrieve context when no valid context

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

    def destroy(self):
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, (self.vao,))
        glDeleteBuffers(1, (self.vbo,))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = App()
```

I've marked the error, it's near the end of the code. The traceback starts at `myApp = App()`.